# How do I get the information about each branch of my git local repository

Tags: bash, git, perl, github

This is what `git branch -v` produces in one of my local directories

```
* develop e229f7a Merge branch 'develop' of https://github.com/me/myremote-repo.git into develop Some diffs
  master  3343dea [behind 2] Added git-log, same as git_log without colorization
```

I am attempting to go through the set of branches and the output from that command and
if the output contains [ahead n] or [behind m], I want to put out a statement like:

```
[behind 2] --> bin [master] 3343dea
[ahead 1]  --> bin [develop] 99345b
```

for each branch IF it contains ahead or behind.

I currently have the following in my code:

```
MOD=`git branch -v | perl -wlne '/^..(\S+)\s+([a-f0-9]+)\s+(\[ahead\s+\d+\]|\[behind\s+\d+\])/ or next; print  "$3 --> $ENV{reponame} [$1] $2"; '`;

    [ ! -z "$MOD" ] &&  MOD="$MOD" | ok=false
    if $ok; then
        echo " OK --> $reponame [$br]"
    else
       # a series of UGLY HACKs to get pretty-printing
       MOD=`echo "$MOD" | tr -d '\011\012\015' | sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//' -e 's/[[:space:]]*$//'` | sed -e 's/]#/]\
 #/'
       if [ ! -z "$MOD" ]; then
          echo -e " $MOD" && continue
       fi
    fi


 bin [develop] --> Out of sync with origin/HEAD at /Users/me/bin
 bin [develop] --> Changes to be staged/committed at /Users/me/bin
 [behind 2] --> bin [master] 3343dea
 OK --> patti [develop]
 OK --> notes [master]
 OK --> indecks [develop]
 OK --> queue [develop]
 OK --> frameworks [develop]
 OK --> nodejs [master]
 OK --> perl-forth [develop]
 OK --> patti [master]
 OK --> blog [develop]
```

The problem is that I only get the first one.  If there are two branches with either a ahead or behind I only get the first one.  I've tried several ways to get the output from git branch -v into an array and then iterate through the array and if it matches the pattern, do the print.  The problem is that I can't find a way to get the output into the array in a way that works.  When I then iterate through the array, I get a list of all the files.

I use:

```
branches={`git branch -v`)
for i in "${branches[@]}"
do
    echo "$i"
done
```

What I get is the list of all the files in the directory!

Why, and what should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `read` in a `while` loop to get the lines from `perl` into `MOD` one by one.

```sh
git branch -v |
perl -wlne'
   print "$3 --> $ENV{reponame} [$1] $2"
      if /^..(\S+)\s+([a-f0-9]+)\s+(\[(?:ahead|behind)\s+\d+\])/
' |
while IFS= read -r MOD; do
   printf '{%s}\n' "$MOD"  # Replace with code that uses $MOD
done
```

Comment: Amazing! May I achieve your skills! -Format?
I changed to:
    if $ok; then
        echo " OK --> $reponame [$br]"
    fi
        git branch -v |
        perl -wlne'
           print "$ENV{reponame} [$1] --> $3 $2"
              if /^..(\S+)\s+([a-f0-9]+)\s+(\[(?:ahead|behind)\s+\d+\])/
        ' |
        while IFS= read -r MOD; do
           printf ' %s\n' "$MOD" 
        done
and it produces
 bin [develop] --> Out of sync
 bin [develop] --> Changes to be staged/committed 
 bin [master] --> [behind 2] 3343dea
 OK --> patti [develop]
 patti [develop] --> [ahead 1] 96e0c9f

Answer (score 3):

I think you can get most of the way there without `perl` or `awk` by specifying the format for the [git branch output](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch). Note that `$REPONAME` is interpolated by the shell because I'm using a double-quoted string. The stuff in `%(...)` is part of the `git` formatting:

```
$ export REPONAME=bin
$ git branch --format "%(upstream:track) --> $REPONAME [%(refname:short)] %(objectname:short=6)" | grep '^\['
[behind 15] --> bin [master] 5b1e08
```

I didn't work very hard on that to get rid of lines where the branch is up-to-date, so I punted to `grep`.

```
$ git branch --format "%(upstream:track) --> $REPONAME [%(refname:short)] %(objectname:short=6)"
  --> bin [a] 5b1e08
  --> bin [briandfoy/how-to-install-perl] 1d7456
[behind 15] --> bin [master] 5b1e08
```

You can add logic, but I didn't get it to the point of not outputting blank lines:

```
$ git branch --format "%(if)%(upstream:track)%(then)%(upstream:track) --> $REPONAME [%(refname:short)] %(objectname:short=6)%(else)%(end)"


[behind 15] --> bin [master] 5b1e08
```

But, I think in your [comment to ikegami](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61112075/2766176) you wanted to have up-to-date branches have "OK". Modify the `if-then-else` to cover just the first column and always output the rest:

```
$ git branch --format "%(if)%(upstream:track)%(then)%(upstream:track)%(else)OK%(end) --> $REPONAME [%(refname:short)] %(objectname:short=6)"
OK --> bin [a] 5b1e08
OK --> bin [briandfoy/some_feature] 1d7456
[behind 15] --> bin [master] 5b1e08
```

If you want some other string for the out of sync branches, just change that branch of the `if-then-else`:

```
$ git branch --format "%(if)%(upstream:track)%(then)Out of sync%(else)OK%(end) --> $REPONAME [%(refname:short)] %(objectname:short=6)"
OK --> bin [a] 5b1e08
OK --> bin [briandfoy/some_feature] 1d7456
Out of sync --> bin [master] 5b1e08
```

You can put the entire format into its own variable, but you need to be careful with that because it interpolates the `$REPONAME`. You'll have to set the `$FORMAT` per repo. I think this is a little easier to digest:

```
$ export FORMAT="%(if)%(upstream:track)%(then)%(upstream:track)%(else)OK%(end) --> $REPONAME [%(refname:short)] %(objectname:short=6)"
$ git branch --format "$FORMAT"
```